# Pandas, strip every cell containing symbol

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column containing currency symbol, I'm looking for an efficient way stripping those symbols so I can convert the column's data type to floats.

Data Frame:

```
          Date     Money(ILS)   
0   2020-05-02     ₪77,000.00   
1   2020-04-30     ₪80,600.00   
2   2020-07-29     ₪86,600.00     
3   2020-10-27    ₪113,963.00     
4   2021-01-25    ₪134,963.00    
5   2021-04-25    ₪155,963.00     
6   2021-07-24    ₪176,963.00     
7   2021-10-22    ₪197,963.00     
8   2022-01-20    ₪218,963.00     
9   2022-04-20    ₪239,963.00     
10  2022-07-19    ₪260,963.00
```

I'm trying to strip the ₪ symbol from the money column.

my function:

```py
@classmethod
    def strip_symbols(cls):
        cls.df = cls.df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('₪') if x.dtype == TypesConsts.OBJECT else x)
        return cls.df
```

with this method I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Comment: As a side note, you probably shouldn't use a float for money. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you applied your lambda function to the **whole** DataFrame (all
columns), so in case of any column of type other than *object* you have
an exception.

Actually you should apply this function **only** to the column (or columns)
holding currency content.

But there is other potential source of problem: If any column has *object*
type, then **usually** all its elements contain **string** data, but there
can be "malicious" cases when some elements contain e.g. *float* data
(*float* is still a descendant of *object*).

Try such an example: Set one element of your DataFrame (*Money(ILS)* column)
to a *float* value:

```
df.iloc[2,1] = 86600.15
```

Then run the code that I suggest (to strip only):

```
df['Money(ILS)'] = df['Money(ILS)'].apply(
    lambda x: x.strip('$') if type(x).__name__ == 'str' else x)
```

(my test data contains *$* as the currency symbol, so I used just *'$'*).

The result is:

```
        Date  Money(ILS)  Other
0 2020-05-02   77,000.00   Abcd
1 2020-04-30   80,600.00  23.16
2 2020-07-29     86600.1   Efgh
3 2020-10-27  113,963.00   Xxxx
4 2021-01-25  134,963.00     35
5 2021-04-25  155,963.00   Yyyy
```

​(I added an additional column and used less rows).

Now:

- all other columns have their original values,
- the currency symbol has been stripped only from cells in *Money(ILS)*
  column,
- but only from those which are of *string* type,
- the only *float* value has been printed as *86600.1* - without the final
  "5", but it is only printing inaccuracy (when you retrieve this cell with
  *iloc*, you will get the proper value).

But to convert this column to *float* you have also to drop commas (beforehand),
also only in **actual** strings:

```
df['Money(ILS)'] = df['Money(ILS)'].apply(
    lambda x: x.replace(',', '') if type(x).__name__ == 'str' else x)
```

**The final solution**

You don't need to do these conversions stepwise. Just use the following code,
doing all in one go:

```
df['Money(ILS)'] = df['Money(ILS)'].apply(lambda x: float(
    x.strip('$').replace(',', '') if type(x).__name__ == 'str' else x))
```

Now when you print the DataFrame:

- *Money(ILS)* is of *float* type (check it with *df.info()*),
- even the *float* value present before has *.15* ending, just as it
  should be.

Of course, apply this code also to another "currency" columns, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for get columns only of object dtype:

```
cols = cls.df.select_dtypes(TypesConsts.OBJECT).columns
cls.df[cols] = cls.df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('₪'))
```